# New exploration package

Tags: ros, navigation, exploration, release, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a simple but functional/complete node for frontier exploration using the hydro costmap_2d layers, but I'm unsure how 'mature' something should be before I should be releasing it.

I thought it was a huge pain that 'explore' was unmaintained, and all the other exploration packages were coupled to larger stacks.

I've ad-hoc tested it pretty thoroughly, and would like to squeeze out some time in a month or so to implement some proper tests and documentation, but for now I'd just like to get the code out there and find out if anyone else is interested in using, contributing, pointing out glaring mistakes, or suggesting functionality.

Is this ready to be released into the wild via bloom?

https://github.com/paulbovbel/frontier_exploration

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137301/new-exploration-package/) by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4518 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-07**:
This looks awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before you do a release, you'll need to add install rules to your CMakeLists.txt. These specify all of the things that will end up in your deb. Messages and services are installed by default, you'll have to write installation rules for everything else such as launch files, executables, libraries, headers, plugin XML files, URDFs, and other resources.

The catkin [common tasks](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html) howto does a good job of describing most of the common cases.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-03-07**:
You should actually try to install your package using `catkin_make install` and then try to use your package from the install space to ensure that everything works as expected.